# Using XSLT prevent output in a foreach based on a previous nodes value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and i've been playing with this most of this morning to get to this point but unsure how to proceed.

This is some test XML to represent what I'm trying to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xslt"?>
<ResultCollection>
    <ColumnSet>
    <Column>
        <Caption>Site</Caption>
        <DisplayType>String</DisplayType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Caption>Date</Caption>
        <DisplayType>String</DisplayType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Caption>Attendee</Caption>
        <DisplayType>String</DisplayType>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Caption>Paid</Caption>
        <DisplayType>Hidden</DisplayType>
    </Column>
    </ColumnSet>
    <RowSet>
        <Row>
            <Site>London</Site>
            <Date>15/06/2012</Date>
            <Attendee>James</Attendee>
            <Paid>Yes</Paid>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Site>London</Site>
            <Date>15/06/2012</Date>
            <Attendee>John</Attendee>
            <Paid>Yes</Paid>
        </Row>
</RowSet>
</ResultCollection>
```

And this is the associated XSLT that i'm using to transform it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table.resultsCollection
{
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px; 
    padding:2px;
}

table.resultsCollection tr th,
table.resultsCollection tr td
{
    padding:2px 8px 2px 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
        <body>
        <table border="1" class="resultsCollection">
            <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
            <xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/ColumnSet/Column">
                <xsl:if test="not(self::*/DisplayType[text()]='Hidden')">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="Caption"/></th>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/RowSet/Row">
                <tr>                
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Site"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Attendee"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Paid"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>   
</xsl:template>
```

I can't change the XML structure that I'm using as that is beyond my control as i think that would make my life easier. Nonetheless my goal is to make it look readable, hence the XSLT.

The problem is that the 'Column' nodes contain a 'DisplayType' which determines if that column should show. With an 'xsl:if' I've made sure that any column with that type won't get displayed. However I can't work out how to follow this through and make sure no associated records are also outputted. If you run these two together you will see the fourth column of the table has no header. But the contents of the the two rows with 'Paid' nodes get outputted regardless.

Any ideas how to sync the two? 
(Any suggestions to prove what I've got is also welcome as this is my first stab at it)

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest you get into the habit of using template rules rather than for-each. So this code:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/RowSet/Row">
        <tr>                
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Site"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Attendee"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Paid"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ResultCollection/RowSet/Row" />
```

plus

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row/*">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Now the change you need to make affects children of Row, i.e. the last template rule. It changes it to this:

```
<xsl:template match="Row/*">
  <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::ResultCollection/ColumnSet/Column[$position]/DisplayType='Hidden')">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the info on templates, very useful. I tried to combine it with Panda34 answers below but had trouble ( used variable for the TH ) but your answer the the row data. I had to change the Row apply template to add 'select="*"' as the position took into account white space.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make a key

```
<xsl:key name="VisibleCols" match="ResultCollection/ColumnSet/Column[DisplayType!='Hidden']" use="Caption"/>
```

and use it like

```
<xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/ColumnSet/Column[DisplayType!='Hidden']">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="Caption"/></th>
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/RowSet/Row">
    <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[key('VisibleCols', name())]">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

note that it doesn't use a predefined set of elements but takes whatever is in source xml which may not be what you want. It also links cells with their headers by column name rather than by their position in xml file (as opposed to other answers).

Added: also, you may use a variable to keep columns in:

```
<xsl:variable name="VisibleCols" select="ResultCollection/ColumnSet/Column[DisplayType!='Hidden']"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$VisibleCols">
    <th><xsl:value-of select="Caption"/></th>
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/RowSet/Row">
    <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:if test="$VisibleCols[Caption=name(current())]">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Great answer as well panda + 1  i tried to make it work but the middle bit with caption=name(current()) wans't playing ball for me, but I did take advantage of what you used for the VisibleCols variable. fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet should produce the correct result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          table.resultsCollection
          {
          border-collapse:collapse;
          text-align:center;
          margin:5px;
          padding:2px;
          }

          table.resultsCollection tr th,
          table.resultsCollection tr td
          {
          padding:2px 8px 2px 8px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1" class="resultsCollection">
          <xsl:variable name="columns" select="ResultCollection/ColumnSet/Column"/>
          <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
            <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
              <xsl:if test="DisplayType!='Hidden'">
                <th>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Caption"/>
                </th>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/RowSet/Row">
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:if test="$columns[$pos]/DisplayType!='Hidden'">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It saves the list of columns in a variable, that is then accessed when processing the rows to check if the column should be displayed or not.

The test on `DisplayType` is semplified - the `[text()]` part is not necessary.

Comment: +1 answer works a treat but went with a combination of the ones above for templates and cleaner code